# How to select specific column from a table that has one to many relationship with another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have 2 tables that have one to many relationship (users & locations) , Each user has one location , But location could have many users.

In `users` table there is a column called `location_id` that is related to the column called `id` in `locations` table.

locations.id -> users.location_id.

So when I want to get all the `users` and their `locations` , I use this code:

```
//Select all the users.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                        FROM users 
                            JOIN locations ON users.location_id = locations.id ');
$stmt->execute();
$values = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

//Loop through the users.
foreach($values as $val){
    $userName = $val['name'];

    //Get The location_id from users table.
    $locationId = $val['location_id']; 

    //Select the location based on this location_id.  
    $st = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * from locations WHERE id = :zid');
    $st->execute(array('zid' => $locationId));
    $v = $st->fetch();
    $location =  $v['location'];
}
```

Is there is a better way for getting the same result?

Comment: You should have all the data you need in the first query. I don't see the point of using the second query.

Comment: @clinomaniac , How is that to get from the first query ?

Comment: SELECT * says get all coumns from all tables

Comment: You have `SELECT *` means you are getting all the columns from user and location tables.

Comment: Looks like you could acutally do `SELECT locations.location
                        FROM users 
                            JOIN locations ON users.location_id = locations.id` and save all sorts of unnecessary data transfer

Comment: i think he also needs the user name though: `SELECT users.name, locations.location FROM users JOIN locations ON users.location_id = locations.id`

Answer (score 2):

this would do the same thing as far as i can tell

```
//Select all the users.
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * 
                        FROM users 
                            JOIN locations ON users.location_id = locations.id ');
$stmt->execute();
$values = $stmt->fetchAll(); 

//Loop through the users.
foreach($values as $val){
    $userName = $val['name'];

    //Get The location
    $location =  $val['location'];
}
```